# PSTricks compilation problem

Tags: errors, pstricks, compiling

The following problems occurred a week ago.  Everything was fine before and the TeX file does compile on my friends computer but does not compile anymore on mine.

When I compile my TeX file I get error messages about the PSTricks:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \c@lor@to@ps \psframe

I use TeXMaker with MikTeX2.9 on Windows 8. I did already install the packages :  `\usepackage{pstricks}` and `\usepackage{pstricks-add}`

I compile with the options : `latex+dvips+ps2pdf+voir Pdf`

I allready uninstall TeXmaker and MikTeX and install them back again.

The code is :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathchoice%
{\overrightarrow{\displaystyle\mathstrut#1\,\,}}%
{\overrightarrow{\textstyle\mathstrut#1\,\,}}%
{\overrightarrow{\scriptstyle\mathstrut#1\,\,}}%
{\overrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle\mathstrut#1\,\,}}}
\def\Oij{$\left(\text{O},~\vect{\imath},~\vect{\jmath}\right)$}
\def\Oijk{$\left(\text{O},~\vect{\imath},~ \vect{\jmath},~ \vect{k}\right)$}
\def\Ouv{$\left(\text{O},~\vect{u},~\vect{v}\right)$}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathbb{D}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\fancyhead[L]{\textit{Terminale S  }}
\fancyhead[R]{\textit{Année scolaire 2014-2015}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{R.Delpuech}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{Lycée des Mascareignes}}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{{\Large Introduction au calcul d'aire - Méthode des rectangles}}
\end{center}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.34,-0.84)(2.46,3.36)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-2.34,-0.84)(2.46,3.36)
\psplot[plotpoints=200]{-2.34}{2.46}{x^(2)}
\begin{scriptsize}
\rput[bl](-2.32,5.98){$f$}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That error typically occurs, if you try to compile a `pstricks` document with `pdflatex`. Try to use `latex` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
% graph.tex
% compile with
% latex graph.tex
% dvips graph.dvi
% ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None graph.ps

\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=200,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    subticks=2,
}
\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(-3.0,-0.5)(3.0,7.0)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(2.5,6.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psplot{-2.5}{2.5}{x^2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]